# Add a reference to the ultimate badge description list

Tags: support, feature-request, status-bydesign, badges

At the moment the [list of Badges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges) has an abbreviated description for each. This is sufficient for some, but not all of the listed badges - mostly those that are hard to obtain. The ultimate badge description list is available on Stack Overflow's Meta site at [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions). I think it would be helpful to add a reference to this post from the badges page?

Any support for this? Or is there a way to improve badge descriptions that are lacking?

<sup>This inquiry was spawned after [@Boris](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris) just obtained the second [Populist Gold Badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist). Congrats! ...and, some regular comments from [@MartinScharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) on chat: [1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=1884352#1884352), [2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=1530910#1530910), [3](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=1065427#1065427), ...</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current thinking is that badges are supposed to be somewhat exploratory in nature, so being extremely explicit about what to do runs counter to the design.

The descriptions are sufficient to get people started, and those that are extra curious will, I am sure, be able to find other resources without too much difficulty.